# Interrupt / Kill a running thread

Tags: java, multithreading

On occurrence of a specific timeout, I need to kill/cancel/interrupt/fail a running thread. I use ExecutorService to manage a pool of threads, through which I am able to cancel the task using the Future's cancel() method which removes this from the ExecutorService's view, but the thread itself continues to run.

Looking around online, people [talk about interrupting threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) that have a loop using the isInterrupted() method or are waiting on IO which can be handled by surfacing InterruptedException.

What is the general practice on killing threads that neither loop (or have any other hooks) and are not waiting on IO? Looking around, Thread.stop() seems to do what I need (just blindly kill the thread) but it is not recommended to be used.

Comment: "blindly kill the thread" is something you shouldn't do, ever.

Comment: Thread.stop() is only fine for trivial pieces of code where you can understand the consequence of stopping at every possible line. This type of code is also simple to add lines to check the interrupted flag. i.e. its not an ideal solution even in theory.

Answer (score 3):

If you use an `ExecutorService` then you should not mess with its threads: this notion is hidden behind the executor which is a higher-level notion than threads and thus does not provide methods to manage them. I strongly advise you to stop the whole Executor and not try to stop one of its threads.

Please note the threads in an `ExecutorService` are looping, their loop includes waiting for a task to be available in their tasks queue.

There is no simple mean in Java to stop a thread that is not looping, what you can do is:

- Have a volatile boolean flag that the thread's `Runnable` checks from time to see if it should stop (the same flag that could be used as a condition in a thread loop).
- Call `Thread.interrupt()` to try (best effort, quite unsafe if you do not know what you are doing) stop a synchronization-related wait/lock/aquire/... the thread is stuck in.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend you to go for the interrupting route since it is the cleanest way and the graceful way to end that thread.

Lets try to well define our objective. A thread is nothing but a separate process going to do a set of tasks that you assign it to do. Probably you will have to find the interruptable points in your code and have to do an interrupted() check at these points. Obviously these points should have reached a logical ending.

For example,

```
public void run(){
      if (Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
           return;
      }
      //LogicA start
      //LogicA end
      if (Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
           return;
      }
      //LogicB start
      //LogicB end
      if (Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
           return;
      }
      //LogicLong start
      //Long code here cannot end or exit or kill the thread now. Let it finish
      //LogicLong ends
      if (Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
           return;
      }
      //LogicD start
      //LogicD end
}
```

Comment: Use Thread.interrupted() with caution: it reset the interruption status of the thread and many classes in the Java API use it, leading to an interruption being unnoticed at the Thread level.

Comment: Not quite. Giving more context here, the thread instantiates a class through an interface and calls specific methods of the class.


The implementation of the methods is defined by the users of my system and I do expect defects like infinite loops. I want to avoid this by killing the jobs that exceed a timeout.

Comment: @NiranjanJayakar : In that case, probably the interruption check should be checked at the beginning of that infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you alread have an `Executorservice` then you have received a `Future` already. The only sane and and clean way to cancel the *job* is therefore calling `future.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`. Setting `mayInterruptIfRunning` will interrupt the jobs if it currently running and does nothing if the job is not running. So you only have to write the job in a way to honour the interruption by checking `Thread.interrupted()` every now and then.

Please note the difference between a *job* and a *thread*. You submit a *job* and therefore you should not muck with a *thread* by trying to circumvent the `ExecutorService` which might be not amused at all about that. Calling `Future.cancel(true)` you give all involved parties a clean signal what to do.

Comment: Agreed. But I want an equivalent of a SIGTERM/SIGKILL combination to the thread. I am unhappy about haveing infinitely running or defective jobs that can be expensive to my system.